# shiny - reactive() to select between two reactive()

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app in Shiny which allows users to upload data or upload a save file.

If a user uploads new data then the flow looks like:

Upload Files >> Select Sheets >> Select Columns >> Sentence Tokenization >> Word Tokenization >> Graphics

Originally, I had been using observe() statements with reactiveValues() so at each step, I stored off the results into a reactiveValues().  This enabled the save file upload to work like:

Upload Save File >> Set sentences >> Set words >> Graphics

I would like to be able to accomplish something similar but using reactive() statements.  So, given that I have `uploadedFiles = reactive()` and `uploadedSave = reactive()` how do I write a reactive with the following pseudo code:

```
rawText = reactive({
  if uploadedFiles() flushes reactivity then uploadedFiles()
  else if uploadedSave() flushes reactivity then uploadedSave()
  else NULL
})
```

I don't have an "error" I'm trying to troubleshoot, just trying to think through the process of using a reactive to act like a 'most recently flushed' gate to allow my data flow to start from two different places and converge to a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to show how I do it, but I have a feeling it is not a great method.  I'm interested in hearing what the best method is and what's wrong with mine.

```
new_react <- reactiveValues()
new_react$FilesReact <- 0 
new_react$SaveReact <- 0

invalidate <- function(x) x <- x+1

uploadedSave <- eventReactive(new_react$SaveReact,{ 
   # Set sentences >> Set words >> Graphics
})


uploadedFiles <- eventReactive(new_react$FilesReact,{ 
  # Select Sheets >> Select Columns >> Sentence Tokenization >> Word Tokenization >> Graphics
})

## I don't know how you are going to determine whether it's a data file
# or a save file...

if (its_a_save_file) {
  new_react$SaveReact <- invalidate(new_react$SaveReact)
  uploadedSave()
}else if (its_a_data_file) {
  new_react$FilesReact <- invalidate(new_react$FilesReact)
  uploadedFiles()
```

So basically I just define two reactive values which when invalidated by that simple function, will allow for the reactive functions, `uploadedSave()` or `uploadedFiles()` to be called.

Edit:  To me, this just looks like a way to force `eventReactive()` to work like `observeEvent()`

Answer (score 0):

Without more code, it is hard to be specific. Here is an app. that displays a different value based on what is the last control used. The controls are monitored using `observeEvent()` and each will put its `input` into a reactive value. Then the  `output` just works with whatever is in the reactive value.  For your case you need to have an `observeEvent()` for each of the controls you are using to do file and save uploads. Then they each put their file into a common `reactiveValue` and that value is used for further processing.

```
library(shiny)

app<-shinyApp(
  ui=(fluidPage(sliderInput("First", min=1, max=10, label="Slider", value=1),
                actionButton("Second", label="Second Button"),
                textOutput("OutText"))
    ),

  server=function(input,output){

    RV<-reactiveValues(data=NULL)

    observeEvent(input$First,
      RV$Text<-input$First)

    observeEvent(input$Second,
       RV$Text<-"Second")

    output$OutText<-renderText({
      req(RV$Text)
      RV$Text
    })
  }
)

runApp(app)
```